# what is the symbol generally used for whole numbers?

Tags: notation, integers

For subjecting to whole numbers, what symbol should I use? it must be valid for using anywhere from school to college. The symbol should be known and well proper to be understood easily by a school student.

Comment: Are the whole numbers the same thing as the natural numbers, to you?

Comment: the whole numbers are not the same as the natural numbers. Not to OP, and not to anybody.

Comment: @IttayWeiss in American schools anyway, my. Impression is that "whole numbers" mean something more like "counting numbers" and do not refer to negative numbers. In fact I even saw that at a college level at the school I most recently taught at. So I do not think it is as clear cut as you. Regards

Comment: @rschwieb I will be very surprised if the american schools redefine the meaning of whole numbers. Whole, or integer (both words mean the same) have a clear meaning, i.e., having no fractional part. Clearly $-5$ is a whole number.

Comment: @IttayWeiss http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_numbers apparently English Wikipedia will surprise you.

Comment: @rschwieb I stand corrected (and I'm shocked). Re-defining 'whole' is just weird.

Comment: @IttayWeiss There's just no consensus on what "whole number" means (nor, as far as I know, has there ever been a consensus). If you want to be precise, you should use one of the following phrases instead: integer, nonnegative integer, positive integer.

Comment: Dear @IttayWeiss : Come now: don't make it look like you believe there are "absolutely correct definitions," that you use them all, and everyone else is a deviant. It would be safer just to exclaim "huh! I didn't ever see that before..." and leave it at that. Besides, it seems entirely natural that "whole" is used in elementary school to contrast "fraction," long before negative numbers are introduced. It's more of a term of natural language than rigorous definition. (Of course an author could make decisions to make it rigorous....) Regards

Answer (score 4):

You can use $\mathbb{Z}$ for the integers, i.e. the set of numbers $\{\cdots, -3, -2 ,-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, \cdots\}$.

Or you can use $\mathbb{N}$ for the cardinal numbers, also called the counting numbers $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots\}$. Sometimes $0$ is included in $\mathbb{N}$ as well.

Comment: It is not true that the standard notation is $0\in \mathbb N$. There is no standard agreement concerning the naturality of $0$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli As far as I know it's a matter of taste or is dictated by the current problem. I just left it in so that the question-asker was aware. :)

Comment: Well, no point arguing, so I deleted my comment. I thought that the absence of a "natural" algebraic structure on $\{1,2,\cdots\}$ made it non-standard, but I am probably wrong.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb N$ generally means $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. It is called the set of *natural numbers*. (Note that sometimes $0$ is included, sometimes it isn't; it depends on the author. If you use the symbol $\mathbb N$, it's a good idea to specify what you mean.)

$\mathbb Z$ means $\{\dots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\dots\}$. It is called the set of *integers*.

If you want a way to refer to $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ (i.e. without $0$) without ambiguity, you could write $\mathbb Z^+$. The superscript $+$ means you're talking about its positive elements.

Answer (score 0):

When I was school in Scotland, it was W for whole numbers ie 0,1,2,...
N for naturals it 1,2,3,...

Z for ...,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...

At Oxford, N was 0,1,2,3,...

These days I use ${\Bbb N}$ for $0,1,2,....$ and
${\Bbb N}_1$ for $1,2,3,...$

The referees for my book "proof patterns" didn't like my notation and wanted me to change but I said no.

Comment: When mathematical convention is consistent and well-established and well-justified and makes perfect sense, there really is no justification to deviate. Nobody uses $W$ for the whole numbers. There is no difference between the whole numbers and the integers. The whole numbers are denoted by $\mathbb Z$. The natural are denoted by $\mathbb N$, though whether or not $0$ is considered natural is not agreed upon.

Comment: except that the standard mathematics textbook series used in all schools in Scotland did. There is a huge amount of disagreement over whether 0 is a natural number.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: You're wrong there. Whole numbers are the nonnegative integers, or, said differently, the naturals along with zero. There's no standard notation for them, but I've seen $\mathbb W$. Sometimes $\mathbb N_0$ or $\mathbb N^*$ seems as good as anything and pretty clear without additional explanation.

Comment: @MPW $\mathbb N^*$ means the set of hypernaturals (the set of sequences of naturals modulo an ultrafilter), so I'm not sure that using the same notation for this other thing is a good idea.

Comment: If it were me, I'd use $\mathbb N$ for $\{0,1,\dots\}$, and I'd use $\mathbb Z^+$, $\mathbb N^+$, $\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$, or some variant for $\{1,2,\dots\}$. (Of course, I would have to specify what I mean by these symbols in the text.)

Comment: I guess the point everyone seems to agree upon is that there really isn't a standard notation.

Comment: The fact you saw $\Bbb N$ used for different purposes in Scotland and Oxford suggests you should avoid the ambiguous $\Bbb N$ entirely. Why not use $\Bbb N_0$ or $\Bbb Z_0^+$ or $\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$ for $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$? It is reasonable to use $\Bbb N_1$ for $\{1,2,\ldots\}$. But of course the best one would be $\Bbb Z^+$.